# Wrapped implementation of a map

Tags: java, multithreading, collections

What's the point of wrapping the map with `Collections.synchronizedCollection(map)`, if then you have to synchronize the code while iterating?

```
  Collection<Type> c = Collections.synchronizedCollection(myCollection);
 synchronized(c) {
        for (Type e : c)
            foo(e); }
```

After having wrapped it, should not be thread safe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What's the point of wrapping the map with Collections.synchronizedCollection(map), if then you have to synchronize the code while iterating?

To make individual operations thread-safe. (Personally I think it's a bad idea in general, but that's a different matter. It's not pointless, just limited in usefulness.)

> After having wrapped it, should not be thread safe?

For any *individual* operation, yes. But iteration involves many steps - and while each of those individual steps will be synchronized, the collection can be modified *between* steps, invalidating the iterator. Don't forget that your loop is expanded to something like:

```
for (Iterator<Type> iterator = c.iterator(); iterator.hasNext(); ) {
    Type e = iterator.next();
    ...
}
```

If you need iteration to be thread-safe, you should use one of the collections in `java.util.concurrent`... while noting the caveats about what is and isn't guaranteed if the collection is modified during iteration.

Answer (score 0):

After wrapping it, each individual method is thread safe, but iteration involves calling methods repeatedly (iterator, then next and hasNext on the returned Iterator) and there's no synchronization between those methods.  This is why you need to synchronize your iteration.

You also need to use a synchronized collection (rather than just synchronizing around your iteration code) because otherwise the methods that add or remove items would not synchronize and therefore could make modifications while you were iterating even if you used a synchronized block.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @jonskeet's @jule's answers, you should consider using `ConcurrentHashMap` (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) which does not require locking around iteration.